# Current in magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

Why does it take more energy to establish a current in a magnet which contains an iron core than in one without an iron core?

Comment: Assuming that we are discussing a solenoid, iron cores have a different permeability compared to air, and thus modify the inductance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a lot more work to push a bunch of magnetic field inside a chunk of iron than it does to do the same in air or a vacuum. This is because in the case of an iron core, the millions of individual magnetic domains inside the bulk iron must each be twisted into alignment with the external field you are imposing on it, and that requires the expenditure of work.